# Define a variable from two other variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PDO and PHP, I'm wondering how I would go about defining vars from the information being pulled from my table.

I have the following:

```
$UID = $_GET['id'];
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND ID = '$UID'");
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "\n";
    echo '<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;zoom=1
    4&amp;size=200x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;sensor=true">';
    echo $row["Nicknames"];
    echo $row["Age"];

}
```

If I try adding:

```
var $name = echo $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'];
```

within my `while` loop the code fails to output anything to my browser.

Comment: If you're using PDO, you should **never** insert user variables directly into your SQL. The [SQL placeholder](http://bobby-tables.com/php) facility is there for a reason. This should be `ID=?` with a `bind_param` call for that after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assigning a variable is done like this,

```
$name = $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname']; //defining variable $name
```

and echo/displaying it, should be done like,

```
echo $name; //this will display whatever is in $name
```

the while loop, as given in the question should work fine, displaying all that you are trying to `echo` out, as long as those keys exist in the resultset.

```
 while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'] . "\n";
echo '<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;zoom=1
4&amp;size=200x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;sensor=true">';
echo $row["Nicknames"];
echo $row["Age"];
}
```

**Edit: (as per comment)**

```
//assign all that you want to display to a variable $map, the equality operator '=' is used for assigning the right-hand side value to the left-hand side variable.
$map = '<img src="maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;zoom=1 4&amp;size=200x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;sensor=true">'; 

echo $map; //display $map
```

**Note:** Variables need to be assigned only if they need to be accessed multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @Coder1984, This doesn't seem to work...
$map = echo '<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;zoom=1
  4&amp;size=200x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;sensor=true">';

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, you are trying to combine 2 different functions, first `assigning a variable $map` and second, `echoing/displaying it`, they need to be done in 2 separate steps, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a keyword only used to declare variables in a class. Thats probably the problem it would be:

```
echo $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'];
```

or

```
$name = $row['First_Name'] . ' ' . $row['Surname'];
echo $name;
```

Additionally youre using preprared statmemnts wrong. Part of the benefit of them is getting your parameters quoted automatically. It should look something like one of the following:

```
// position placeholders
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND ID = ?");
$sth->execute(array($UID));
```

or

```
// names palceholders
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND ID = :uid");
$sth->execute(array(':uid' => $UID));
```

Comment: thanks @prodigitalson, This doesn't seem to work... $map = echo '<img src="maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='; . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;zoom=1 4&amp;size=200x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|' . $row["Location_Postcode_Last_Seen"] . '&amp;sensor=true">';

Comment: assing the string to `$map` THEN `echo $map` not both at the same time. If you must do them both at the same time then you actually do them in reverse like `echo ($map = 'the string for map');`

Comment: I dont understand the difference between the prepared statement you have written and mine? What do you mean it would quote my paramaters automatically?

Comment: You have put in `ID = '$UID'` so you are manually quoting it and not necessarily in the correct way, nor are you escaping its contents. That way i did it, you let PDO quote the parameter and escape it for the db.